# Kafka JDBC source connector time stamp mode failing for sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I tried to set up a database with two tables in sqlite. Once of my table is having a timestamp column . I am trying to implement timestamp mode to capture incremental changes in the DB. Kafka connect is failing with the below error:

```
 ERROR Failed to get current time from DB using Sqlite and query 'SELECT 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' 
(io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.SqliteDatabaseDialect:471)
java.sql.SQLException: Error parsing time stamp

Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2019-02-05 02:05:29" 
does not match (\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q 
\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q.\E(\p{Nd}++)
```

Many thanks for the help

Config:

```
name=test-query-sqlite-jdbc-autoincrement 
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector 
tasks.max=1 
connection.url=jdbc:sqlite:employee.db 
query=SELECT users.id, users.name, transactions.timestamp, transactions.payment_type FROM users JOIN transactions ON (users.id = transactions.user_id) 
mode=timestamp 
timestamp.column.name=timestamp 
topic.prefix=test-joined
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions(id integer primary key not null,
                          payment_type text not null,
                          timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT(STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'NOW')),
                          user_id int not null, 
                          constraint fk foreign key(user_id) references users(id)
); 

CREATE TABLE users (id integer primary key not null,name text not null);
```

Comment: Can you share your table DDL and Connector config?

Comment: The timestamp needs to include milllisecond precision, according to the error

Comment: @cricket_007    The error is getting generated from the internal query in the internal class of io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.SqliteDatabaseDialect during bootstrapping. For custom query , I have included milliseconds precision.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt  DDL - CREATE TABLE transactions(id integer primary key not null,payment_type text not null,timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT(STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'NOW')),user_id int not null, constraint fk foreign key(user_id) references users(id));

Comment: @DDeveloper please update your question with *both* DDL statements, and your Connector config. Thanks.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt sharing the props file <br/> name=test-query-sqlite-jdbc-autoincrement
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:sqlite:employee.db
query=SELECT users.id, users.name, transactions.timestamp, transactions.payment_type FROM users JOIN transactions ON (users.id = transactions.user_id)
mode=timestamp
timestamp.column.name=timestamp
topic.prefix=test-joined

Comment: Help us to help you… you said there are TWO tables, I've asked twice… please can you provide the DDL for BOTH tables. Also edit your question instead of pasting the DDL as a comment, it makes it easier to view.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Update the same. Kindly suggest if you need any more information

Comment: You have hours, minutes, seconds in `02:05:29`. Not milliseconds...

Answer (score 1):

The kafka connect jdbc connector easily detects the changes in the timestamp, if the values of the 'timestamp' column are in the format of the 'UNIX timestamp'.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE transact(timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (STRFTIME('%s', 'now')) not null,
   ...> id integer primary key not null,
   ...> payment_type text not null);
sqlite>
```

The values can be inserted as:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO transact(timestamp,payment_type,id) VALUES (STRFTIME('%s', 'now'),'cash',1);
```

The timestamp related changes are then detected by the kafka jdbc source connector and the same can be consumed as follows:

```
kafka-console-consumer  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic jdbc-transact --from-beginning
{"timestamp":1562321516,"id":2,"payment_type":"card"}
{"timestamp":1562321790,"id":1,"payment_type":"online"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced this, and it is already logged as an issue for the JDBC Source connector. You can monitor it here: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/219