# kafka jdbc source connector: time stamp mode is not working for sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I tried to set up a database with a table with timestamp column . I am trying to implement timestamp mode to capture incremental changes in the DB.

But kafka-connect-jdbc is not reading any data from the table. Here is what I have done.

Created a table.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test_timestamp(id integer primary key not null,
   ...>                   payment_type text not null,
   ...>                   Timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   ...>                   user_id int not null);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test_timestamp (ID, PAYMENT_TYPE, USER_ID) VALUES (3,'FOO',1);
sqlite> select * from test_timestamp;
3|FOO|2019-06-18 05:31:22|1
```

My jdbc-source connector configuration is as follows:

```
$ curl -s "http://localhost:8083/connectors/jdbc-source/config"|jq '.'
{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
  "mode": "timestamp",
  "timestamp.column.name": "timestamp",
  "topic.prefix": "testdb-",
  "validate.non.null": "false",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "name": "jdbc-source",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlite:/tmp/test.db"
}
```

jdbc-source-connector successfully loads and topic is created

```
$ kafka-topics --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
..
testdb-test_timestamp
```

But no data appears in the topic.

Any help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try to include `"query": "select * from test_timestamp"` in the configuration?

Comment: Yes. I have added this in the configuration file but have no luck.

Comment: Looks like this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518763/kafka-jdbc-source-connector-time-stamp-mode-failing-for-sqlite3  Also your timestamp column name is "Timestamp" and not "timestamp", try changing that.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across similar issue. In my case, even the topic didn't create. Found out that timezone for connect worker must be same as that of DB. Setting db.timezone property in the connect worker's property file correctly based on this [list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) (under SHORT_IDS section) makes it work:

```
db.timezone=Asia/Kolkata
```

Comment: This was **exactly** what I needed, and it solved my problem after 1h+ of debugging! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting a known issue, detailed here: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/219

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create database:

   ```
   $ echo 'DROP TABLE test_timestamp; CREATE TABLE test_timestamp(id integer primary key not null,
                    payment_type text not null,
                    Timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                    user_id int not null);
   INSERT INTO test_timestamp (ID, PAYMENT_TYPE, USER_ID) VALUES (3,\'FOO\',1);
   select * from test_timestamp;' | sqlite3 /tmp/test.db
   3|FOO|2019-07-03 08:28:43|1
   ```
2. Create connector

   ```
   curl -X PUT "http://localhost:8083/connectors/jdbc-source/config" -H  "Content-Type:application/json"  -d '{
   "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
   "mode": "timestamp",
   "timestamp.column.name": "timestamp",
   "topic.prefix": "testdb-",
   "validate.non.null": "false",
   "tasks.max": "1",
   "name": "jdbc-source",
   "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlite:/tmp/test.db"
   }'
   ```
3. Check status of connector

   ```
   $ curl -s "http://localhost:8083/connectors"| \
   jq '.[]'| \
   xargs -I{connector_name} curl -s "http://localhost:8083/connectors/"{connector_name}"/status"| \
   jq -c -M '[.name,.connector.state,.tasks[].state]|join(":|:")'| \
   column -s : -t| sed 's/\"//g'| sort
   jdbc-source  |  RUNNING  |  RUNNING
   ```
4. Check Kafka Connect worker log, observe error parsing date, per [issue 219](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/219)

   ```
   [2019-07-03 10:40:58,260] ERROR Failed to run query for table TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{table="test_timestamp", query='null', topicPrefix='testdb-', incrementingColumn='', timestampColumns=[timestamp]}: {} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:332)
   java.sql.SQLException: Error parsing time stamp
       at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getTimestamp(JDBC3ResultSet.java:576)
       at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.currentTimeOnDB(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:484)
       at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.endTimetampValue(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:203)
       at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingCriteria.setQueryParametersTimestamp(TimestampIncrementingCriteria.java:164)
       at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingCriteria.setQueryParameters(TimestampIncrementingCriteria.java:126)
       at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.executeQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:176)
       at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TableQuerier.java:92)
       at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:60)
       at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask.poll(JdbcSourceTask.java:310)
       at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.poll(WorkerSourceTask.java:245)
       at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:221)
       at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
       at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2019-07-03 08:40:58" does not match (\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q \E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q.\E(\p{Nd}++)
       at org.sqlite.date.FastDateParser.parse(FastDateParser.java:299)
       at org.sqlite.date.FastDateFormat.parse(FastDateFormat.java:490)
       at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getTimestamp(JDBC3ResultSet.java:573)
       ... 17 more
   ```